# C3 comboBox different display and value members but need to access both

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a dataset that has multiple columns which include a Text value to display and a numeric value that I need to use for filtering an another combobox.

```
            MyComboBox.DisplayMember = "Reason";
            MyComboBox.ValueMember = "ReasonID";
            MyComboBox.DataSource = MyDataTable;
```

The issue I have is that part of the code I need the ID however for another part of the code I need the text. I can get the ID back but I'm not sure how to access the text when the value changes. I've tried the following

```
            String test1 = MyComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            String test2 = MyComboBox.SelectedText.ToString();
```

Test1  is the ID as I expected. However test2 is "" and I can't see any properties that give the display value instead of the selected value.

Comment: Windows Forms, right? Did you try [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)? `SelectedText` isn't what you think it is, it's the text the user selects with the mouse if the combobox is editable.

Comment: yes I had tried it. the result was "System.Data.DataRowView" but the answer below from Fabio was what I was trying to do.

Comment: Right, your items are DataRowView and SelectedItem is the selected one. You could cast SelectedItem to that type and get any property you want from it: For example `((System.Data.DataRowView)MyComboBox.SelectedItem)["Reason"].ToString()`. `ComboBox.Text` solves the problem more simply, but now you know what SelectedItem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ComboBox.Text Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

```
string value = MyComboBox.Text;
```

`Text` property contains value of `DisplayMember` of selected item in your case.

About `ComboBox.SelectedText` from MSDN

> Gets or sets the text that is selected in the editable portion of a
>   ComboBox.

So this is not a text of selected item

Comment: doh... thanks I was having a complete blonde moment. I knew there had to be something simple I was missing.